# tesseract OCR in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract open source engine for OCR to read text from image. 
But I didn't get 100% result for a single time. Please give your suggestions about quality improvement for OCR using tesseract.
Thanks

Comment: Leave some details such as your image, the results you got, how your results are incorrect, and which Tesseract commands you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how to get best result from tesseract
Please make sure that you have done preprocessing on image. OVR will produce best results for the images which have following properties:

1. fix DPI (if needed) 300 DPI is minimum
2. fix text size (e.g. 12 pt should be ok)
3. try to fix text lines (deskew and dewarp text)
4. try to fix illumination of image (e.g. no dark part of image
5. binarize and de-noise image

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tesseract-ocr/g5aE_OvgyTU